# How do I reverse words in a string with Python

Tags: python, string, reverse

I am trying to reverse words of a string, but having difficulty, any assistance will be appreciated:

```
S = " what is my name"

def reversStr(S):
    for x in range(len(S)):
        return S[::-1]
        break
```

What I get now is: `eman ym si tahw`

However, I am trying to get: `tahw is ym eman` (individual words reversed)

Comment: How should "Hello, I am a hat." be reversed? Starting with ",olleH" or "olleH,"?

Comment: Why are you using `return` immediately?

Comment: You are trying to reverse the letters in the words inside a string, not reverse the string itself?

Comment: @JoshTriiJohnston Yes....

Comment: That's not in-place; you're just reversing the order of the letters in each word. "In place" has a very specific meaning when it comes to data structures; it means you're modifying the actual input object, not returning a new object based on the input. You can't reverse a Python string in-place, because Python strings are immutable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
def reverseStr(s):
  return ' '.join([x[::-1] for x in s.split(' ')])
```

Comment: I am a little confused. Will ``s.split(' ')`` consume extra memory space so that it's not in-place?

Comment: @AaronZeng I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: My apologizes. I assume ``s.split(' ')`` splits the string into a new list, which causes additional space allocation, so it's not "in place". Am I correct here?

Comment: Yes it will, this allocates a new list of words, reverses each word in the list, and then joins the words back together.

Comment: Then since string is not mutable, I assume we cannot reverse a string in Python if no extra space is allowed. Is that right? I am working on this algorithm problem: http://www.programcreek.com/2014/05/leetcode-reverse-words-in-a-string-ii-java/

Comment: Yes you are right, strings are immutable in Python , so for any kind of string manipulation you have to convert it in the list.

Answer (score 1):

```
orig = "what is my name"
reverse = ""
for word in orig.split():
    reverse = "{} {}".format(reverse, word[::-1])
print(reverse)
```

Comment: That is an interesting algorithm you have there, although it does add a leading space to the resulting string.

Comment: It's also expensive, as you are creating a new string object each time through the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Since everyone else's covered the case where the punctuation moves, I'll cover the one where you don't want the punctuation to move.

```
import re
def reverse_words(sentence):
    return re.sub(r'[a-zA-Z]+', lambda x : x.group()[::-1], sentence)
```

Breaking this down.

`re` is python's regex module, and [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) is the function in that module that handles substitutions. It has three required parameters.

The first is the regex you're matching by. In this case, I'm using `r'\w+'`. The r denotes a raw string, `[a-zA-Z]` matches all letters, and `+` means "at least one".

The second is either a string to substitute in, or a function that takes in a re.MatchObject and outputs a string. I'm using a `lambda` (or nameless) function that simply outputs the matched string, reversed.

The third is the string you want to do a find in a replace in.

So "What is my name?" -> "tahW si ym eman?"

Addendum:

I considered a regex of `r'\w+'` initially, because better unicode support (if the right flags are given), but `\w` also includes numbers and underscores. Matching `-` might also be desired behavior: the regexes would be `r'[a-zA-Z-]+'` (note trailing hyphen) and `r'[\w-]+'` but then you'd probably want to not match double-dashes (ie `--`) so more regex modifications might be needed.

The built-in `reversed` outputs a `reversed` object, which you have to cast back to string, so I generally prefer the `[::-1]` option.

Answer (score 1):

`inplace` refers to modifying the object without creating a copy. Yes, like many of us has already pointed out that python strings are immutable. So technically we cannot reverse a python `string` datatype object `inplace`. However, if you use a mutable datatype, say `bytearray` for storing the string characters, you can actually reverse it `inplace`

```
#slicing creates copy; implies not-inplace reversing
def rev(x):
    return x[-1::-1]

# inplace reversing, if input is bytearray datatype
def rev_inplace(x: bytearray):
    i = 0; j = len(x)-1
    while i<j:
        t = x[i]
        x[i] = x[j]
        x[j] = t
        i += 1; j -= 1
    return x
```

Input:

```
x = bytearray(b'some string to reverse')      
rev_inplace(x)
```

Output:

```
bytearray(b'esrever ot gnirts emose')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting each word in the string into a list (see: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

Example:

```
>>string = "This will be split up"
>>string_list = string.split(" ")
>>string_list
>>['This', 'will', 'be', 'split', 'up']
```

Then iterate through the list and reverse each constituent list item (i.e. word) which you have working already.

Answer (score 0):

```
def reverse_in_place(phrase):
    res = []
    phrase = phrase.split(" ")
    for word in phrase:
        word = word[::-1]
        res.append(word)
    res = " ".join(res)
    return res
```

Comment: Good answers *explain* as well as provide code. Consider updating your answer to include an explanation about how this code works and why it is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

[thread has been closed, but IMO, not well answered]

the python string.lib doesn't include an in place str.reverse() method.
So use the built in reversed() function call to accomplish the same thing.

>>> S = " what is my name"
>>> ("").join(reversed(S))
 'eman ym si tahw'

Comment: welcome to [so], thanks for your answer.  Your answer seems not answer the question (`tahw is ym eman`).

Comment: What Prisoner said - and also `S[::-1]` is the normal way to reverse a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
def rev(a):
    if a == "":
        return ""
    else:
        z = rev(a[1:]) + a[0]
        return z
```

Reverse string --> gnirts esreveR

```
def rev(k):
    y = rev(k).split()
    for i in range(len(y)-1,-1,-1):
        print y[i],
```

-->esreveR gnirts

Answer (score 0):

There is no obvious way of reversing a string "truly" in-place with Python. However, you can do something like:

```
def reverse_string_inplace(string):
    w = len(string)-1
    p = w
    while True:
        q = string[p]
        string = ' ' + string + q
        w -= 1
        if w < 0:
            break
    return string[(p+1)*2:]
```

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, strings are immutable. This means you cannot change the string once you have created it. So in-place reverse is not possible.

There are many ways to reverse the string in python, but memory allocation is required for that reversed string.

```
print(' '.join(word[::-1] for word in string))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s1 = input("Enter a string with multiple words:")

print(f'Original:{s1}')
print(f'Reverse is:{s1[::-1]}')

each_word_new_list = []

s1_split = s1.split()

for i in range(0,len(s1_split)):
    each_word_new_list.append(s1_split[i][::-1])

print(f'New Reverse as List:{each_word_new_list}')

each_word_new_string=' '.join(each_word_new_list)

print(f'New Reverse as String:{each_word_new_string}')
```

Answer (score 0):

If the sentence contains multiple spaces then usage of `split()` function will cause trouble because you won't know then how many spaces you need to rejoin after you reverse each word in the sentence. Below snippet might help:

```
# Sentence having multiple spaces
given_str = "I  know this   country runs by mafia "
tmp = ""
tmp_list = []
for i in given_str:
    if i != ' ':
        tmp = tmp + i
    else:      
        if tmp == "":
            tmp_list.append(i)
        else:
            tmp_list.append(tmp)
            tmp_list.append(i)
            tmp = ""

print(tmp_list)
rev_list = []
for x in tmp_list:
    rev = x[::-1]
    rev_list.append(rev)
print(rev_list)
print(''.join(rev_list))
```

output:
[image]